# sinch video chat not showing local view or remote view

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I have integrated sinch video chat in my application based of sinch video push sample

The local view and remote view only show black screen and does not show anything and it generate this crash in background

```
03-28 12:02:59.371 16607-19169/com.forsale.forsale E/Logging: VideoCapturerAndroid: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                              at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:568)
                                                              at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:405)
                                                              at org.webrtc.sinch.VideoCapturerAndroid.startCaptureOnCameraThread(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:450)
                                                              at org.webrtc.sinch.VideoCapturerAndroid.access$1100(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:47)
                                                              at org.webrtc.sinch.VideoCapturerAndroid$7.run(VideoCapturerAndroid.java:460)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

can any one help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside Manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
```

Do not forget to request permissions like here discribed:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

In breif:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 50);
}    else {       


   startCamera();
```

}

Comment: I am already putting the permissions in my manifest file, but I will check the part of request permission and let you know the result.

Comment: yes the part of request permission is working with me, Thanks a lot